# Convert JSON keys to set in different columns with preset headers in pandas

Tags: json, pandas, flatten, normalize

Want to implement dataframe expansion from JSON data with preset values. Collating all the key values within `JSON` data to be set as column headers

```
id   |Name | MonthWise 
0    |ABC  |{'102022':{'val':100, 'count':1}}
1    |XYZ  |{'102022':{'val':20,'count':5},'092022':{'val':20,'count':2}}
2    |DEF  |{}
3    |PQR  |{'082022':{'val':50,'count':3}}
```

Here `df` containing `MonthWise` column which has `JSON` objects, which needs to transposed into 12 different columns like `'MMYYYY'` (Yearly data)

Something like:

```
id |Name |042022.val | 042022.count |....|102022.val | 102022.count|....| 032023.val| 032023.count
0  |ABC  |nan|nan|....|100|1|....|nan|nan
1  |XYZ  |nan|nan|....|20|5|....|nan|nan
2  |DEF  |nan|nan|....|nan|nan|....|nan|nan
3  |PQR  |nan|nan|....|nan|nan|....|nan|nan
```

I have tried with `df['MonthWise'].apply(pd.json_normalize(x, max_level=1))` but no success.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `apply` in this case. You may use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) as follows

```
import pandas as pd

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'Name': ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'DEF', 'PQR'],
    'MonthWise': [{'102022':{'val':100, 'count':1}}, {'102022':{'val':20,'count':5},'092022':{'val':20,'count':2}}, {}, {'082022':{'val':50,'count':3}}]
})

# normalize
result = pd.concat([df[['id','Name']], pd.json_normalize(df['MonthWise'])], axis=1)
```

This returns

```
   id Name  102022.val  102022.count  092022.val  092022.count  082022.val  082022.count
0   0  ABC       100.0           1.0         NaN           NaN         NaN           NaN
1   1  XYZ        20.0           5.0        20.0           2.0         NaN           NaN
2   2  DEF         NaN           NaN         NaN           NaN         NaN           NaN
3   3  PQR         NaN           NaN         NaN           NaN        50.0           3.0
```

(I believe that the expected result in your original post is inconsistent with the input dataframe)